# Get ajax dropdown base on parent id return undefined in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I try to get list of `city` of my chosen `state(province)` and city names return as `undefined`

here is my controller methods

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $rajaongkir = new Rajaongkir\Domestic('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        $province = $rajaongkir->province();

        $origin = 152; //Jakarta
        $destination = 178; // Kediri
        $weight = 1;
        $courier = 'tiki'; // jne, tiki, pos
        $cost = $rajaongkir->cost($origin, $destination, $weight, $courier);
        return view('front.raja', compact('province', 'cost'));
    }

    public function getCityList($province)
    {
        $rajaongkir = new Rajaongkir\Domestic('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        $city = $rajaongkir->city($province);
        return response()->json($city);
    }
```

my blade codes:

```
<form action="">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <select name="province" id="">
                    <option class="form-control" value="">Select Province</option>
                    @foreach ($province->data as $info)
                        <option value="{{$info->province_id}}">{{$info->province}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                <select name="city" id="">
                    <option class="form-control" value="">Select City</option>
                </select>

                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
                    Destination:
                        {{$cost->meta['destination']->province}},
                        {{$cost->meta['destination']->type}},
                        {{$cost->meta['destination']->city_name}},
                        {{$cost->meta['destination']->postal_code}}.
                    @foreach($cost->data as $option)
                          <h3>{{$option->code}} <small>{{$option->name}}</small></h3>
                           @foreach($option->costs as $cost)
                                 @foreach($cost->cost as $c)
                                     <label class="radio">
                                        <input name="post" value="{{ $c->value }}" type="radio">{{$cost->service}} / {{ $c->value }} Rp - {{ $c->etd }} hari @if(!empty($c->note))- {{ $c->note }} @endif
                                    </label>        
                                @endforeach             
                          @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">save</button>
            </form>
```

my javascript codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="province"]').on('change', function() {
        var provinceID = $(this).val();
            if(provinceID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('get-city-list') }}/'+encodeURI(provinceID),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('select[name="city"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['city_id'] +'">'+ value['city_name'] + ' - ' + value['type'] +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
            }else{
            $('select[name="city"]').empty();
              }
           });
        });
</script>
```

here is result of my codes:

[image: screen1]

> If I add `alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4));` before `append` will
>   return:

[image: screen2]

Here is what I try to achieve in total `Logic`:

1. Choose Province
2. Get City list of that Province
3. Get Id of that city and add it as my `$destination` in Index function `$destination = 178; // Kediri`

> The point is all this has happen with ajax, why? because I try to use
>   this form in my cart before checkout so when I hit checkout button is
>   already included shipping price.

Comment: If that is the result of your `alert(JSON.stringify(value)` that should tell you that `value` is a multi level. Have you tried `value[0]['city_name']`?

Comment: @Sean it makes it empty drop box.

Comment: You should see what `console.log(data);` is, that looks like you should be doing a double `$.each` or determining if `data` is an array that contains nested arrays as mentioned that can be isolated like `$.each(data[0],function(){..etc})`

Comment: @Rasclatt this is what i get on console  https://ibb.co/bLihgw

Comment: so is `data.data` an object? So if you do `console.log(data.data);` does it give undefined or that data object?

Comment: @Rasclatt the result https://ibb.co/cqCKTb

Comment: Do `$.each(data.data` instead of just `$.each(data`. That is the object that contains the actual data

Comment: @Rasclatt please make a comment, but before that: do you have idea about my logic no.3? (end of my question)

Comment: When is that method called? I don't use Laravel, so I don't really know when you are calling that. Is that what the ajax is calling or when is that method triggered?

Comment: @Rasclatt i did not create method for that part yet but i want to get id of selected city back to my controller. so i can use it in my index function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comments, it appears you are trying to iterate the wrong object:

Use:

```
$.each(data.data
```

Instead of just:

```
 $.each(data
```

This is because your `data` from the ajax success comes back as:

```
{
    code:200,
    data:[
        ...etc.
    ],
    error: ...etc.
}
```

Comment: continue our conversation: currently i get my city list base on provinces (thanks to you) now I want get `city_id` to my form (look at my first screenshot in question) and base on that id data of radio button changes. so i need to extend my `js` code i think to make that happen. `any idea?`

Comment: You want to do this via ajax?

Comment: it doesnt matter to me with what, i just thought if with ajax can load calculation without refreshing page `thats what im looking for'

Comment: what do you think?